# Convert ASN.1 to human-readable format

Tags: c#, java, vb.net, perl

I have ASN.1 format files. I have to convert into CSV(comma separated) format also readable one. Tell me the shortest way... Like Decoders etc.

Comment: Can you provide short examples of the expected results from conversions of [ASN.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) input to CSV and 'human readable' form?

Comment: "tell me" is unnecessarily rude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link to a [encoding/decoding asn1 module](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Convert::ASN1) for Perl. I have never used it but it seems simple enough.